# Set dropdown above for Android Auto complete textview

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I want to set the dropdown of an autoCompleteTextView above the input field. Is there any attribute or method around to set the dropdown always on top ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `android:dropDownAnchor`. Learn more about this [AutoCompleteTextView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html#attr_android:dropDownAnchor)

**Edit**

Try setting `android:dropDownAnchor`along with `android:dropDownHeight,android:dropDownHorizontalOffset, android:dropDownVerticalOffset` to get desired position

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:dropDownAnchor="@id/textView"
    android:dropDownHeight="100dp"
    android:dropDownWidth="200dp"
    android:text=""
    android:dropDownVerticalOffset="120dp"
    android:dropDownHorizontalOffset="0dp"/>
```

Comment: that does not provide any effect.

Comment: My bad. Updated my answer

Comment: Nice one brother, I was looking for this exact attributes in the official doc...missed somehow. Thanks a lot.

Comment: what is `@id/textView` here? it seems to refer to another component, which isn't in your posted XML

Comment: @AdamBurley It's another View to anchor the autocomplete dropdown.

Answer (score -1):

**In your layout**

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginLeft="36dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:text="">
```

**Java Code**

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                (this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, fruits);
        //Getting the instance of AutoCompleteTextView
        AutoCompleteTextView actv = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView);
        actv.setThreshold(1);//will start working from first character
        actv.setAdapter(adapter);//setting the adapter data into the
```

Comment: this just looks like general info about how to set up an `AutoCompleteTextView` and does not answer this particular question